# Как получить id фильма с сайта кинопоиск?

Tags: python

Как получить id фильма с сайта кинопоиск?
Научил бот при запросе "фильм Терминатор" (например) выдавать:
"Фильм: Терминатор. Год выхода: 1984. Жанр фильма: боевик, триллер, фантастика. Место съёмок: Великобритания, США". Но не могу понять какой командой прикрутить чтоб ещё постер брал.

````
        result = re.sub(r'фильм ', '', message.text.lower())
        search = kinopoisk.search(result)
        for item in search:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фильм: ' + item.ru_name + '. Год выхода: ' + item.year + '. Жанр фильма: ' + ", ".join(item.genres)
            + '. Место съёмок: ' + ", ".join(item.countries))```
````